# Finding ideals of a finite semigroup machinery (GAP)

Tags: semigroups, gap

As you see, I did a finite semigroup and then try to find its possible ideals in a very basic way (with the hand of a friend):

```
  > f:=FreeSemigroup("a","b");;  
    a:=f.1;;  b:=f.2;; 
    s:=f/[[a^3,a],[b^2,a^2],[b*a,a*b^3]];;
    e:=Elements(s);;
    w1:=List([1..Size(e)],i->Elements(SemigroupIdealByGenerators(s,[e[i]])));;
    w2:=DuplicateFreeList(w1);;
    w3 := Combinations(w2);;
    for i in [1..Size(w3)] do
      w3[i] := DuplicateFreeList(Flat(w3[i]));;
    od;;
    w3 := DuplicateFreeList(w3); 

 > [ [  ], [ b*a*b, b, b^2, b*a, b*a^2 ], [ a, a^2, a*b, a^2*b ] ]
```

Do you think that above codes suffice to make them visible appropriately? Thanks for your attention!

Comment: I am a bit confused but maybe I am misintrepreting the Gap code. It seems that $ba = ab^3 = ab^2b = aa^2b = a^3b = ab$. Thus your semigroup is commutative. On the other hand, you have both a*b and b*a in the final line, which seems to indicate that these elements are distinct.

Comment: Yes! That's right. Maybe it happens cause of using an old version of GAP. I usualy use Alexander Hulpke's windows frendly one[http://www.math.colostate.edu/~hulpke/CGT/education.html]. Thanks for the point. :-)

Comment: @J.-E.Pin GAP recognises here that $ab=ba$. If you call `w4:=DuplicateFreeList(Flat(w3));` it will return `[ b*a*b, b, b^2, b*a, b*a^2 ]`. The code in question simply have $ab$ and $ba$ in different sublists.

Comment: @s-snape Please do so, but I might be a bit slow to answer if the question is too difficult...

Comment: @s-snape Please delete this comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of theory, for finite semigroups:

- every ideal in a semigroup is a union of principal ideals (the least ideal containing a given single element)
- two elements in a finite semigroup generate the same principal ideal if and only if they are $\mathscr{D}$-related (this is the definition of being $\mathscr{D}$-related).
- the relation $\mathscr{D}$ is an equivalence relation, and its equivalence classes are called $\mathscr{D}$-classes
- if $A$ and $B$ are $\mathscr{D}$-classes, then we say that $A \leq_{\mathscr{D}} B$ if the the principal ideal generated by any (and all) elements in $A$ is contained in the principal ideal generated by any (and all) elements in $B$.

So, if you know the $\mathscr{D}$-classes of a finite semigroup, and the partial order $\leq_{\mathscr{D}}$, then you know everything about the ideals of the semigroup, and how they are interrelated.

In GAP, you can do:

```
T := Range(IsomorphismTransformationSemigroup(s));
DClasses(T);
```

you will see that your semigroup has two $\mathscr{D}$-classes and hence two ideals. If you have the [Semigroups](http://tinyurl.com/semigroups) package, then you can also do:

```
Splash(DotDClasses(T));
```

and obtain the following picture of the $\mathscr{D}$-classes and their partial order:

### [image: D-class diagram]

You can also see that your semigroups is a copy of the direct product of the cyclic group of order 2 with itself, with an additional non-regular element on the top. The ideals are: the whole semigroup, and the group $C_2\times C_2$.