# GAP tells this semigroup is not a group.

Tags: semigroups, gap, inverse-semigroups

**Happy *Nowruz 2016* to every one here!**

Using the code which James pointed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1559036/8581); I was playing with the following finite semigroup:

```
gap > f:=FreeSemigroup("a","b");;  
      a:=f.1;;  b:=f.2;; 
      w:=f/[[a^4,a],[b^2,a^3],[b*a,a^2*b],[b^3,b]];;
      T=Range(IsomorphismTransformationSemigroup(w));;
```

GAP tells us that `T` has $6$ elements, is regular (Inverse) and has just one idempotent. This means that `T` is a finite group [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/421394/8581).

But, by calling another codes `AsGroup(T)` and `IsGroup(T)` both would end to undesirable results `failed` and `false` respectively. Is there anything obvious I cannot see well?

Thanks for the time.

Comment: Your attempt to apply `AsGroup` is correct. I don't know why it returns `fail`, since `AsGroup(MagmaByMultiplicationTable(MultiplicationTable(AsList(T))));` returns a group. But in the other attempt `IsGroup` is of no help here since it checks the category of the object, and not its mathematical property.

Comment: Thanks Alexander for the points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alex is correct: `IsGroup` only returns `true` if the object it is applied to belongs to the category of groups. This means that certain operations make sense for the object, such as inversion (via `Inverse` or `^ -1`), and `One`. Since transformations don't always have an inverse, this means that they sometimes don't belong to the category of groups even though they do define a group mathematically. Just to make life more complicated they also do sometimes belong to the category of groups but let's not get into that.

The thing to check is `IsGroupAsSemigroup` which checks that the object mathematically defines a group, whether it belongs in the category of groups or not. Also you can do `IsomorphismPermGroup` to give an isomorphism permutation group.

With the [Semigroups](http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~jamesm/semigroups.php) package loaded you will get:

```
gap> IsGroupAsSemigroup(T);
true
gap> IsomorphismPermGroup(T);
MappingByFunction( <transformation group of degree 7 with 2 generators>
, Group([ (2,3,4)(5,6,7), (2,7)(3,6)
(4,5) ]), <Attribute "PermutationOfImage">, function( x ) ... end )
```

Neither `IsGroupAsSemigroup` nor `IsomorphismPermGroup` work in GAP without the [Semigroups](http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~jamesm/semigroups.php) package.

I don't know why `AsGroup` returns `fail`, the [documentation](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X7A0747F17B50D967) is a bit vague. This is probably a bug.

Comment: Thanks James for paving the way. I need time to reflect about the points.

Comment: This is something that trips up many GAP users, including me. `IsMonoid` is another example, it does not return `true` for something that is mathematically a monoid but is not in the category of monoids.

Comment: Can I call 'StructureDescription' to find out the related possible group after appling 'IsomorphismPermGroup' under 'Xmod' package?

Comment: Yes, you can, do 'StrucureDescription(Range(map));' where 'map' is the variable holding the isomorphism to a perm group.  This has nothing to do with the xmod package, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Thanks so much James for every seconds. :-)